# summation notation for the tensor product of two operators

Tags: tensor-products

Suppose there exists a linear operator $A$ from the vector space $V$ to $V'$ and a linear operator $B$ from the vector space $W$ to $W'$.

I.e., $A:V \rightarrow V'$ and $B:W \rightarrow W'$.

The operator $C: V \bigotimes W \rightarrow V' \bigotimes W'$ is described by

$C = \sum_{i}c_{i}A_{i}\bigotimes B_{i}$.

The confusion I have stems from my understanding that there exists only *one* operator mapping elements a vector space to another vector space so the appearance of a subscript with the operator $A$ and $B$ seems to contradict my understanding.

Any clarification to assist with my understanding is greatly appreciated.

Source: http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf

Page 101/ 704 wrt **PDF page viewer**.

Comment: In general there are _lots_ of operators mapping elements from one vector space to elements of another. And given $A:V\rightarrow A'$ and $B:W\rightarrow W'$ there is a canonical thing $A\otimes B$ but it certainly isn't defined by the formula you give for $C$. I think there is some context missing here. Where does that formula come from? Are $A,B$ _arbitrary_ linear operators between the given spaces or are they of some special form?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan You are correct - and I haven't missed that crucial point. In this context, there is only one arbitrary operator given by the author so that the map from V to V' and W to W' occurs. I have included the text to which I refer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text cited is perhaps less than perfectly clear. What it's saying is:

Suppose $C$ is any linear map from $V\otimes W$ to $V'\otimes W'$. Then *it can be written as* a sum $\sum_i c_i A_i\otimes B_i$ where each $A_i\otimes B_i$ is the tensor product of a map $A_i:V\rightarrow V'$ and a map $B_i:W\rightarrow W'$.

To be explicit about a couple of things that *aren't* happening here:

- The indices here aren't coordinate indices.
- There isn't a specific map $A:V\rightarrow V'$ or a specific map $B:W\rightarrow W'$ at this point. (There are some maps with those names further up the page, where the authors are explaining what the notation $A\otimes B$ means.)
- In particular, $A_i$ and $B_i$ aren't things derived from some single $A$ and $B$.

The claim is just that if you pick a map $C$ between $V\otimes W$ and $V'\otimes W'$ then there will be *some* $c_i,A_i,B_i$ that do the trick. In other words, even though most linear maps $V\otimes W\rightarrow V'\otimes W'$ aren't of the form $A\otimes B$, there are enough of those to span the space of linear maps $V\otimes W\rightarrow V'\otimes W'$.